# How to get the Target parameter of an Action?

Tags: c#

I have a class that has an Action:

```
Action<string> Binding;
```

I need to get the Target parameters called terrainTag, shown as below.

[image]

I need to access terrainTag and do changes with it.

How should I do it?
I did a lot of research online but I couldn't find anything helpful yet.

The Target returns with a weird Type that couldn't be looped through.

```
object {Terrain.Views.TerrainManager.<>c__DisplayClass8_0}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Delegate.Target`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate.target?view=net-7.0) is an `object`, you need to cast it to something useful before using it.

Alternatively, you can use late binding, like so:

```
dynamic target = label.Binding.Target;
dynamic terrainTag = target.terrainTag;
```

I cannot express enough how incredibly bad it is that you even think you need such a thing. You are absolutely using delegates wrong.

Comment: It didn't work. How should I cast Delegate.Target in order to be able to loop through it?

Comment: @Wiley `It didn't work.` How.

Comment: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'terrainTag''